# why are names not being added to the list?

Tags: javascript, html

I found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZWxq/1/) and I am trying to get it to work...I can not figure out why the names are not being added to the list, for some reason Add button is acting like a submit button and I can not tell why...It should add all the numbers to a list so when I click submit, then it should send the numbers in an array..

JavaScript:

```
function bindName() {
    var inputNames = document.getElementById("names").getElementsByTagName("inputNames");
    for (i = 0; i < inputNames.length; i++) {
        inputNames[i].onkeydown = function() {
            if (this.value == "") {
                setTimeout(deletename(this), 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("addName").onclick = function() {

    var num1 = document.getElementById("name");

    var myRegEx = /^[0-9]{10}$/;


    var myRegEx = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
    var itemsToTest = num1.value;


    if (myRegEx.test(itemsToTest)) {


        var form1 = document.getElementById("names");

        var nameOfnames = form1.getElementsByTagName("inputNames").length;

        var newGuy1 = document.createElement("inputNames");

        newGuy1.setAttribute("id", nameOfnames);
        newGuy1.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newGuy1.setAttribute("value", num1.value);

        form1.appendChild(newGuy1);
        num1.value = "";
        bindName();

    }
    else {
        alert('error');
    }


};
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Enter Name</h1>
<div id="mainName">
    <h2>name</h2>
    <label for="name">Add Names: </label>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <button id="addName">Add</button>
    <form>
        <div id="names">

        </div>
        <input METHOD="POST" action="text.php" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: because there is no tag `inputNames`

Comment: Well the inputName tags get created but you can only submit values of standard form elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen

```
document.createElement("inputNames");
```

Shouldn't be

```
document.createElement("input");
```

?

Comment: The problem got semi fixed, the numbers DO added into the list but as soon as they do once you click "Add" the submit button gets triggered too I cant tell why :S

Answer (score 0):

Because this `/^[0-9]{10}$/;` will accept only 10 numbers and only that, try entering `1234567890` and you will see no error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your "name" field is restricted to 10 digit numbers, but I've got the thing to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/y8Uju/4/

I think the problem was that you were trying to create an element with the tag name inputNames, but that's not a valid tag. Instead I changed it to create inputs, and set the class to inputNames.